# error in setting up dynupdater5.4.0-2

Tags: linux-mint, apt

I wanted install `dynupdater 5.4.0-2` in linux mint.  When I type the command:

```
apt-get update dynupdater 5.4.0-2
```

it says I must install `libpgm-5.1.0`, I force the install of it with this command:

```
apt-get -f install libpgm-5.1.0
```

and after that it automatically sets dynupdater.  But it freezes at:

```
Setting up dynupdater (5.4.0-2) ...
```

after a long time on this I restart computer but when I want to use synaptic, it always says that:

```
(synaptic:3486): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_hide: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

I try this command:

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

and again it freezes on

```
Setting up dynupdater (5.4.0-2) ...
```

I don't know what too do.

Please help thanks!

Comment: If you see 1 CPU core used 100 % of time (e.g. in `htop` started in console) it indicates a programming error and you should consider filing a bug report to the `dynupdater` developers.

Comment: Strictly speaking if it freezes at "Setting up dynupdater" it's a packaging bug, but AFAICS the dynupdater packagers are the dynupdater developers so in this instance filing a bug report with the dynupdater developers is the right approach.